# Horizontal list view images

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create categories list of images using Horizontal list view. But it is not rendering an image. I have created two variable for different images and try to implement for them. It doesn't give any error in the terminal.  Where I am wrong? Thank you in advance.

pubspec.yaml

```
assets:     
    - assets/shirticon.png
    - assets/shoeicon.png
    - assets/mobileicon.png
    - assets/gunicon.png
    - assets/pantsicon.png
```

view code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
  const HorizontalList({super.key});    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80.0,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: const <Widget>[
          Category(
            image_location: 'assets/shirticon.png',
            image_caption: 'shirt',
          ),
         Category(
            image_location: 'assets/shoeicon.png',
            image_caption: 'shoe',
          ),
         Category(
            image_location: 'assets/mobileicon.png',
            image_caption: 'mobile',
          ),
         Category(
            image_location: 'assets/gunicon.png',
            image_caption: 'gun',
          ),
         Category(
            image_location: 'assets/pantsicon.png',
            image_caption: 'pants',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}    
class Category extends StatelessWidget {    
  final String image_location;
  final String image_caption;    
  const Category({super.key, 
   required this.image_location,
   required this.image_caption,
  });    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          width: 100.0,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Image.asset(
              image_location,
              width: 100.0,
              height: 80,
              ),
            subtitle: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Text(image_caption),
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. Also make to sure add on pubspec.yaml, If fails can you include `Category`

Comment: are you having this problem in web?

Comment: @eamirho3ein yeah i am running this all in web...

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have included all code here. I did futter clean and rebuild the app too.

Comment: can you test on different device/emulator, everything seems working fine

Answer (score 0):

You probably wrote the image name wrong in pubspec.yaml, if you are sure that the name is ok then try `flutter clean` and `flutter pub upgrade`.

Comment: Yeah, the name is OK.

Comment: I'm glad that helps you to fix your problem, I appreciate if you give it approve and up vote too.

Comment: No, i just said the names are all ok, The problem might be different.